# Updating Database Using Datagridview

Tags: c#, addition, edit, updates

I can add, edit, delete database using listbox. But I want to do it using DatagridView I already bind it to my database.

How do I add,edit,delete update my database in datagridview using codes?

These are my codes:

```
namespace Icabales.Homer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\homer\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Icabales.Homer\Icabales.Homer\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void bindgrid()
    {
        string command = "select * from info";
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(command, cn);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.info' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.infoTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.info);
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        loadlist();
        bindgrid();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtid.Text != "" & txtname.Text != "")
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into info (id,name) values ('" + txtid.Text + "' , '" + txtname.Text + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Clone();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted");
            cn.Close();
            txtid.Text = "";
            txtname.Text = "";
            loadlist();
        }
    }
    private void loadlist()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        cn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from info";
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                listBox2.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
            }
        }
        cn.Close();             
    }

    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox l = sender as ListBox;
        if (l.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = l.SelectedIndex;
            listBox2.SelectedIndex = l.SelectedIndex;
            txtid.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            txtname.Text = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtid.Text != "" & txtname.Text != "")
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "delete from info where id = '"+txtid.Text+"'and name = '"+txtname.Text+"'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted");
            loadlist();
            txtid.Text = "";
            txtname.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtid.Text != "" & txtname.Text != "" & listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "update info set id='"+txtid.Text+"',name='"+txtname.Text+"'where id='"+listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()+"' and name='"+listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()+"'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated");
            loadlist();
            txtid.Text = "";
            txtname.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

I have a dataGridView and a button on a form. When I do any editing, insertion or deletion in the dataGridView1, the code below does the magic

```
public partial class EditPermit : Form
{
     OleDbCommand command;
     OleDbDataAdapter da;
     private BindingSource bindingSource = null;
     private OleDbCommandBuilder oleCommandBuilder = null;
     DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    public EditPermit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void EditPermitPermit_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataBind();                           
    }

    private void btnSv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         dataGridView1.EndEdit(); //very important step
         da.Update(dataTable);
         MessageBox.Show("Updated");        
         DataBind(); 
    }

    private void DataBind()
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataTable.Clear();

        String connectionString = MainWindow.GetConnectionString(); //use your connection string please
        String queryString1 = "SELECT * FROM TblPermitType"; // Use your table please

        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = queryString1;
        try
        {
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryString1, connection);
            oleCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
            da.Fill(dataTable);
            bindingSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = dataTable }; 
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a solution that inserts/updates/deletes data in MS SQL database directly from DataGridView.
To accomplish this I have used the following events: RowValidating and UserDeletingRow.

It is supposed that you have

```
SqlConnection _conn;
```

declared and initialized.
Here is the code:

```
    private void dgv_RowValidating( object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e )
    {
        try
        {
            if (!dgv.IsCurrentRowDirty)
                return;

            string query = GetInsertOrUpdateSql(e);
            if (_conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                _conn.Open();

            var cmd = new SqlCommand( query, _conn );
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show( ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning );
        }
    }

    public string GetInsertOrUpdateSql( DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e )
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        int id = 0;
        int.TryParse( row.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString(), out id );

        DateTime dob;
        DateTime.TryParse( row.Cells["Dob"].Value.ToString(), out dob );

        string email = row.Cells["Email"].Value.ToString();
        string phone = row.Cells["Phone"].Value.ToString();
        string fio = row.Cells["Fio"].Value.ToString();

        if (id == 0)
            return string.Format( "insert into {0}  Values ('{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')", "dbo.People", fio, dob.ToString( "dd-MM-yyyy" ), email, phone );
        else
            return string.Format( "update {0} set Fio='{1}', Dob='{2}', Email='{3}', Phone='{4}' WHERE Id={5}", "dbo.People", fio, dob.ToString( "dd-MM-yyyy" ), email, phone, id );
    }
    private void dgv_UserDeletingRow( object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e )
    {
        try
        {
            int id = 0;
            int.TryParse( e.Row.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString(), out id );
            string query = string.Format( "DELETE FROM {0} WHERE Id = {1}", "dbo.People", id );
            var cmd = new SqlCommand( query, _conn );
            if (_conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                _conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show( ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning );
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Liked that friend. That helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same kind of project at home, I do not have the source code with me but if needed I can check somewhere this weekend to see what exactly I have done, but I believe it's some of the following:

Since you are using a `dataset` and a `dataadapter` this can be achieved very easily.

As long as your `DataGridView1` has the properties enabled for users to add/delete/edit rows you could use the following code.

```
DataAdapter.Update(DataTable);
//in your code this would be:
da.Update(dt);
```

The `DataAdapter.Update()` Method will auto generate any insert/update/delete commands needed to update the results of your fill query compared with the current data in your `datagridview`.
You can set those commands (properties) as well in case you prefer to modify them, though this is not necessary.

This only works ofcourse after a user has made changes to the `DataGridView`. Add this code to a simple button and see if you have any luck. It definitly was something this simple :)

Comment: @HOmer you could add it in a `button_click` event for example.

Comment: how do i use it? can i put it on the method loadlist?

Comment: place the code in the method where you want to save you're datagridview changes into the database. Putting in the loadlist method might work yes. Though personally, for testing purposes, I would create a new button and datagridview. And then when the button is clicked to save the data, and load the second datagridview to see if it loads the changes.