# Update database with values in DataGridView using C#

Tags: c#, .net

How can I update the values in the database with the values in the DataGridRow when the button is clicked?

To be precise i want to change the text of column from "En cours" to "PRET" when i click the button

[image]

```
public void ajoutercolonne()
{
    DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
    btn.Name = "Validation";
    btn.Text = "Prêt";
    btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
    dataGridView2.Columns.Add(btn);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating Database Using Datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065443/updating-database-using-datagridview)

Answer (score 0):

Use a ado.net request tu update here is a example:

```
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database.mdf;Trusted_Connection=True; 
       User Instance=yes");
  conn.Open();
  string sql2 = "UPDATE student SET moneyspent = " + ?????? + " WHERE id=" + studentIndex + ";";
  SqlCommand myCommand2 = new. 
  SqlCommand(sql2, conn);
```

See slso here:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/save-delete-search-and-update-record-in-ado-net/

Comment: Wide open to sql injection, do not do this.